# Java "error: illegal start of type" when throwing an IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java

I'm trying to code up a (brute-force) solution in Java to the two-sum problem:

```
import java.lang.*;

public class TwoSum {
    public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i+1; j < nums.length; j++) {
                if (nums[j] == target - nums[i]) {
                    return new int[] {i, j};
                }
            }
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("No two sum solution");
}
```

However, when I try to compile it I get the following errors:

```
/home/kurt/Documents/Algorithms/TwoSum.java:13: error: illegal start of type
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("No two sum solution");
    ^
/home/kurt/Documents/Algorithms/TwoSum.java:13: error: ';' expected
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("No two sum solution");
         ^
/home/kurt/Documents/Algorithms/TwoSum.java:13: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("No two sum solution");
              ^
/home/kurt/Documents/Algorithms/TwoSum.java:13: error: illegal start of type
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("No two sum solution");
                                       ^
4 errors
[Finished in 0.8s with exit code 1]
```

I'm a bit stumped what might be causing the error? (I took the code from an example snippet but don't notice any differences).

Comment: It's just a typo: You've put the `throw` *outside* the method. Move it to just one line higher up, *inside* the method's `{...}`. Voting to close as typo/non-repro.

Comment: `throw new IllegalArgumentException("No two sum solution");` is declared at the class level. It is not allowed. It should be in `twoSum()` as last statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following code:

```
import java.lang.*;

public class TwoSum {
    public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i+1; j < nums.length; j++) {
                if (nums[j] == target - nums[i]) {
                    return new int[] {i, j};
                }
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No two sum solution");
    }
}
```

In this case `throw new IllegalArgumentException("No two sum solution");` is inside method.